# Way to speed up jQuery UI Dialog creation on a large amount of HTML?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with a large amount of HTML in it that I am trying to create a jQuery dialog on. This process is very slow (about 8 seconds in IE) which is unacceptable. It is usually very fast to create a dialog but with a large amount of markup it apparently isn't.

I understand the reason for part of the performance issue is that it will remove and append the section to create the dialog on to the end of the DOM which is slow for such a large amount of HTML.

Is there any way to speed up the process by creating parts of the markup necessary for the modal manually, tricking jQuery UI into not moving the HTML or something else? I have already tried:

- making the modal not re-sizable
- making the modal not movable
- wrapping the table in another

I would like to continue to use the jQuery UI markup since we are using it elsewhere and have already spent the time to style it appropriately. Thanks!

Here is a very simple example that demonstrates the problem:

http://johnculviner.com/modaltest.html

Comment: need to show some code, creating one dialog doesn't take long, sounds like something elses slowing it down

Comment: this has been my experience in the past with jQuery UI Dialog with a small amount of markup. Since this is a lot of markup I believe it is bogging it down. I updated the question with a link with just the bare bones HTML and JavaScript

Comment: one thing is you should construct the dialog on page load...then just trigger open  **especially** if you are resuing it

Comment: thanks for the thought, unfortunately the performance hit still remains (and oddly enough still when the button is clicked). here is a new demo of your idea: http://johnculviner.com/modaltestonDOMready.html

Comment: another suggestion, add width 100% to table. Big table I think is the issue. I use dialogs all the time, and open them with ajax content and never run into this. Might also add meta charset on page BTW

Comment: yeah tables... sigh... tried your suggestions and no dice still unfortunately. I wish jQuery didn't do so much 'mucking' with the markup and it would be fast

Comment: it's not jquery, all it has to do is wrap a couple of elements. It's the browser and that big table. You could strip off most of the rows and add them after dialog opens. cache them to a variable with detach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with the best solution I could find with some advice from charlietfl. Made a post on it here: http://johnculviner.com/a-jquery-ui-dialog-open-performance-issue-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: @RoyiNamir What does that question has to do with this one.

Comment: @Foreever I don't know either , probably wrong paste location

Answer (score 1):

here's a possible suggestion:

1.) create your dialog html table with ~20 rows.
2.) create the dialog widget and dialog click handler on document ready.
3.) outside of document.ready, create a self-invoking function that will add the remaining table rows.

here's a demo i created with this approach [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/Z8BNq/)

Comment: thanks for the thought! This still took around 7 seconds in IE (compared to 8 before). The data also is from a database and I was just plugging in the fake data to make an example

Answer (score 0):

**width: $(window).width()**

**height: $(window).height()**

set the dialog height and width with the current viewport width. you will find it loading much faster.

this is because when you set the dialog width statically and when the dialog is loaded it has to compress the contents to the size of the dialog which takes time.